# Next.js rendering dynamic content via paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dynamic-data

**Want to Achieve**

I have two links that have dynamic paths. When I click on either of them, I want my local data to be dynamically displayed based on which link is clicked.

**Issue**

Clicking on either of the two links brings me to a 404 page. I'm 100% certain my setup is wrong and I'm in the right direction, but can't seem to figure out how to implement my dynamic paths to render with the associated data.

**My Code**

- My data is a json file that lives in the root of my project within a folder **`data/posts.json`**

```
[
   {
    "title": "Array",
    "description": "Arrays are ......"
  },

  {
    "title": "Objects",
    "description": "Objects are......"
  }
]
```

- My page paths sit in **`pages/posts/[id].js`**

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

import Layout from '../../layout/layout'

const Post = ({data}) => {
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
      <p>{data.description}</p>


      <style jsx>{`
        h1, p {
          text-align: center;
        }  
      `}</style>
    </Layout>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Read file directory
  const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data')
  const filenames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)

  // Read and parse JSON file
  const fileData = filenames.map(filename => {
    const filePath = path.join(postsDirectory, filename)
    const fileContents = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'))

    return {
      filename,
      content: fileContents,
    }
  })

  const data = fileData[0].content

  return {
    props: {
      data: data[query.id]
    },
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { id: 'arrays' } },
      { params: { id: 'objects' } }
    ],
    fallback: false
  };
}


export default Post
```

- My main index.js file which sits in **`pages/index.js`**

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

import Layout from '../layout/layout'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Banner from '../components/banner'
import CardContainer from './../components/card';

const Home = ({data}) => {
  console.log(data);

  const titleData = data.map(item => item.title)

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Banner />
      <CardContainer titleData={titleData}/>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Read file directory
  const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data')
  const filenames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)

  // Read and parse JSON file
  const fileData = filenames.map(filename => {
    const filePath = path.join(postsDirectory, filename)
    const fileContents = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'))

    return {
      filename,
      content: fileContents,
    }
  })

  const data = fileData[0].content

  return {
    props: {
      data
    },
  }
}

export default Home
```

My `CardContainer` component is where the link to each page sits:

```js
<Link href='/posts/[id]' as={`/posts/${title}`}>
    <img src={img} alt="card image" />
</Link>
```

The `title` prop is the title from my json data which matches the page path like so:

**`http://localhost:3000/posts/arrays`**

**`http://localhost:3000/posts/objects`**

**Research I've done**

I have checked the following examples but wasn't able to figure it out as my data is local and not from an API.

[next.js pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

[fetching data for pages](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-data-for-pages)

[markdown blog with Next.js](https://dev.to/tinacms/creating-a-markdown-blog-with-next-js-52hk)

Comment: hey. Did you manage to figure this out? It has been hard to find stuff related to Nextjs that goes beyond that silly introductory stuff. Hard to find support even here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Alioshr I fully agree with you. Unfortunately, I didn't end up figuring this out. If I do, I'll be sure to come back and comment / update.